# Biginteger auto_increment primary key Phinx

Tags: cakephp, auto-increment, phinx

I am trying to create a migration with a biginteger-primary key and switch it to **auto_increment**.

I am using **robmorgans Phinx** to create the migration.

Is it possible to change a table's primary key of the datatype BIGINTEGER to be auto_incremented after you've created it?

Currently it looks like this.

```
$positions = $this->table('positions', ['id' => false, 'primary_key' => 'id'])
        ->changeColumn('id', 'biginteger', ['auto_increment' => true])
        ->addColumn('work_order_id', 'char', ['after' => 'vehicle_id','default' => null, 'null' => true,'limit' => 36])
        ->update();
```

Comment: Please add an actual question to your question - thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `auto_increment` option, see

**https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#valid-column-options**

What you are looking for is the `identity` option, which will, quote

> enable or disable automatic incrementing

```
->changeColumn('id', 'biginteger', ['identity' => true])
```

Comment: How could i miss.. :) Thanks alot ndm!!